# Split string into 3 parts using regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, split

How do I split the following string:

```
.p SomeNickname some very long text
```

into

1. `.p`
2. `SomeNickname`
3. `some very long text`

Comment: You don't need a regular expression for this. Just use `string.split(' ')` to get an array of words. You can then put elements 2 to the end back together with `join()`.

Comment: `".p SomeNickname some very long text".split(/(\.\w+)\s+(\w+)\s([\w\s]+)/).filter(String)`

Comment: @dandavis, thanks, exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`".p SomeNickname some very long text".split(/(\.\w+)\s+(\w+)\s([\w\s]+)/).filter(String)"` worked for me by @dandavis

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what exactly you want to do, but you can try the build-in method split()  in JavaScript.

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript Strings</h1>
<h2>The split() Method</h2>

<p>split() splits a string into an array of substrings, and returns the array.</p>

<p>The first word is:</p>
<p id="demo_0"></p>

<p>The second word is:</p>
<p id="demo_1"></p>

You also can use a loop to make it easier.

<script>
let text = ".p SomeNickname some very long text";
const myArray = text.split(" ");

document.getElementById("demo_0").innerHTML = myArray[0]; // .p
document.getElementById("demo_1").innerHTML = myArray[1]; // SomeNickname

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

For further information try this link: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Good Luck !!!!

Comment: You might add that the 'very long text` can also be retrieved by removing the first two elements of the array, and joining the remainder with the missing spaces: `myArray.shift();myArray.shift(); longText = myArray.join(" ");`

Answer (score 0):

we can split this using `split.Text()` function